# why degree of algebraic variety $V(x^2+y^2-1)$ is two?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

From [the book chapter 8](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611972702.ch8), It is stated on page 148 that

*The degree of an m-dimensional irreducible algebraic set X, written degX, is the number of points in the intersection of X with a general linear space of codimension m.*

I am trying to deduce the degree of $V(x^2+y^2-1)$ by the above statement, and here is my thought, but I think there is something wrong with it:

Thus the degree of the algebraic variety $V(x^2+y^2-1)$ is the number of points in the intersection of X with a general linear space of codimension m. Since the codimension of a general linear space is m, the dimension of it should be $N-m$, which is $2-2=0$ right? thus the degree of the algebraic variety $V(x^2+y^2-1)$ is the number of points in the intersection of X with a general linear space of dimension $0$.

Could anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Your $X$ is $1$-dimensional, so $m=1$. (It's a circle in the plane) A codimension $1$ linear subspace of the plane is a line. In how many points does a general line intersect your curve?

Comment: @ViktorVaughn In complex plane, almost every line intersect the curve with two isolated points, so degree of the curve should be 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your $X$ is $1$-dimensional, so $m=1$. (It's a circle in the plane) A
> codimension 1 linear subspace of the plane is a line. In how many
> points does a general line intersect your curve? – Viktor Vaughn

> @ViktorVaughn In complex plane, almost every line intersect the curve
> with two isolated points, so degree of the curve should be 2. Thanks!
> –  HJ_dynamics